# как считывать несколько строк на входе?

Tags: python, python-3.x

надо считать входные данные которые подаются рандомным количеством строк и с пробелами колличество которых достигает до 10^9 и засунуть это все в массив.
в версии python 3.6.2 это делается так:

```
    import sys
    values=[]
    for line in sys.stdin:
        for word in line.split():
            values.append(word)
```

но в более поздних версиях это перестало так работать.
при вводе

```
 1427  0   

   876652098643267843 
5276538
```

в массив сохраняется только числа из первой строки.
как например на python 3.7 считать данные сразу из несколько строк, некоторые из которых могут быть пустыми?

Comment: `line.split()` - `split` это, метод у строки. А ещё проще будет сделать так

`values.extend(line.split())`

Answer (score 0):

Перепроверьте дебагом, у меня под Python 3.7.1 ваша конструкция работает. Только добавил условие выхода (слово exit) и печать результата.

```
import sys

values = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.split():
        values.append(word)
        if word == 'exit':
            print(values)
            sys.exit(0)
```

Вывод выглядит так:

```
1232131 11
   123123123123123

5464564 456456446
      66666
exit
['1232131', '11', '123123123123123', '5464564', '456456446', '66666', 'exit']

Process finished with exit code 0
```